# Is it possible to insert a layout between ActionbarSherlock and Tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I want to insert a custom layout like Youtube application.

Here are the screenshots, what I want is green bordered as you understand. As far as I know Google is using native ActionBar, but I want to learn if it is possible using ActionBarSherlock and also, only if it is possible using ActionBar, how can I do this?

[image: first]...[image: second]

Comment: No. That's not how the [ActionBar API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) works.

Comment: First, thank you Jake for your reply. I took a look at ActionBar API and it uses the same code as me, the only difference is I'm using your library and also viewpager. I could not find any example how can I insert a layout green bordered in my printscreents using ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do this with the native or ActionBarSherlock tabs. You should use one of the below great libraries. They are easy to use and you can get the above look very easily.

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

or

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip